# Getters & Setters Objective C vs C#

Tags: c#, objective-c, getter-setter

what is the best way to replicate the c# code below in objective c.

I am using the setter method to add some additional functionallty.

```
    void someMethod()
    {
        speed = 10; //_speed is 10
        speed++;//_speed is now 11
        speed += 70;//_speed is now 86
        speed += 12324;//_speed is clamped to 100 in setter
    }

    int _speed;
    public int speed
    {
        get { return _speed; }
        set { _speed = value;
            if (_speed > 100)
            {
                _speed = 100;
            }
        }
    }
```

I know I can do something like this in obj c

```
@property (nonatomic,assign) NSInteger speed;
```

which then makes these methods available

```
-(void)setSpeed:(NSInteger)speed
{

}

-(void)getSpeed:(<#object-type#> **)buffer range:(NSRange)inRange
{
}
```

however I am uncertain how I can actually access the property internally in my class. What I would like to be able to do is somewhere else in the class instance (and / or from the instantiating object as well) is set speed by doing something like speed = 50 and know the code in the setter will ensure it never exceeds the max.

I hope this makes sense!

Thanks!

Comment: **Side note: In obj-c `get` is not supposed to be prefixed to methods.

Comment: oops slip of the fingers going from c# to obj-c!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Xcode automatically generates the getters and the setters for you when you define the properties, so you have them already, you can access them like this:

```
self.speed = 5;
int mySpeed = self.speed;
```

In case you want to overwrite this setter, you can do it:

```
-(void)setSpeed:(NSInteger)speed
{
    if (speed > maxSpeed)
        _speed = maxSpeed;
    else
        _speed = speed;
}
```

Take into account that when you use objects, if you implement the setter, you need to release the previous value and retain the new one.